# Config for WCF with multiple endpoints

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest, soap

I'm new to WCF and am trying to get some ideas I have off the ground.

Basically I have a web WCF Application project with the following in its web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="WcfService1.ServiceContract.IDirectorySearchService" behaviorConfiguration="defaultServiceBehavior"> 
            <endpoint name="restxml" address="xml" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.ServiceContract.IDirectorySearchServiceXml" behaviorConfiguration="xmlRestBehavior"/>
            <endpoint name="restjson" address="json" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.ServiceContract.IDirectorySearchServiceJson" behaviorConfiguration="jsonRestBehavior"/>
            <endpoint name="soap" address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.ServiceContract.IDirectorySearchService"/>
            <endpoint name="mex" address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="defaultServiceBehavior"> 
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="xmlRestBehavior">
                <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
            <behavior name="jsonRestBehavior">
                <enableWebScript/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

My interfaces look like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IDirectorySearchServiceXml  
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Search/")]
    SearchResults Search();
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IDirectorySearchServiceJson  
{ 
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Search/")]
    SearchResults Search();
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IDirectorySearchService
{
    [OperationContract]
    SearchResults Search(int? sportId, int? instituteId, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate);
}
```

Now the part I am having a little trouble with is what else I need to get this up and running... Like given this what .svc files do I need and do I have the config right... Also what addresses do I need to use to get this running either through the browser or through the WCF test client. Note I am currently using 3.5.

Cheers
Anthony

UPDATE:

So If I have something like the following, I would need 3 different svc files... If this is the case then there isn't much point in having address part in the end point...

```
public class DirectorySearchServiceXml : IDirectorySearchServiceXml  
{
    ...
}

public class DirectorySearchServiceJson : IDirectorySearchServiceJson  
{ 
    ...
}

public class DirectorySearchService : IDirectorySearchService
{
    ...
}
```

But I could create 1 class that exsplictly implments all 3 interfaces, then I would only have 1 svc and then the address becomes relevent... Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, if you have **three classes** that implement the service contract, you need **three SVC files**. If you have just **one class** implementing all three interfaces, then you need **one SVC file** - one SVC file per class that implements your contracts

Comment: I have made one class implementing all three interfaces and I am getting the following error: "Service 'WcfService1.Service.DirectorySearchService' has zero application (non-infrastructure) endpoints. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no service element matching the service name could be found in the configuration file, or because no endpoints were defined in the service element." any ideas? My config is as above, and the svc looks like <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WcfService1.Service.DirectorySearchService" %>

Comment: and the url I'm using is "http://localhost:16089/DirectorySearchService.svc/mex"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends :-)

If you want to host your WCF services in IIS (check out MSDN [How To: Host a WCF Service in IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx)) as I assume from your question, then you need three things:

- a virtual directory (and possibly a subdirectory thereof) where you'll put your service file (yourservice.svc) into
- a service file - a short one-liner
- an appropriate config section in your web.config

The service file (*.svc) is just a tiny one-line text file to instruct IIS how to create your service. It looks like this:

```
<%@ServiceHost language=c# Debug="true" 
               Service="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.CalculatorService"%>
```

The `language` attribute defines the language of the WCF service, `debug` enables debugging (for dev and test, disable it for production), and the `Service=` defines which class (fully qualified with namespace and all) actually implements your service(s).

Next, you either need to put those service implementations into a code-behind file of the *.svc (not recommended), or - much better - compile your WCF service implementation into a class library and stick that class library into the `.\bin` directory under your virtual directory.

And in the end, you need appropriate config in your server-side web.config - from what I can tell, you already have that in place, and I think it should be just fine.

Your service addresses will be determined by the

- server
- virtual directory (and possible subdirectories)
- the service file itself

and any additional settings you might have in your config for the individual service endpoints.

So in your case, you'd have

- `http://yourserver:port/YourVirtualDirectory/YourService.svc/restxml`
- `http://yourserver:port/YourVirtualDirectory/YourService.svc/restjson`
- `http://yourserver:port/YourVirtualDirectory/YourService.svc/soap`

for your real functions, and a * `http://yourserver:port/YourVirtualDirectory/YourService.svc/mex` for the metadata exchange (which you won't use directly).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback... big question I have is, for the interfaces I have and the config I want, what svc's do i need and what are their names? Do I only need the 1 svc which points to default service?

Comment: @vdh_ant: you need **one SVC file per service class** that you have. If you have a single service class that implements all three service contracts, then you need **one SVC file** - when you have three separate classes each implementing one of the service contracts, then you need **three SVC files** - one per service class. What you name it is totally up to you - whatever you like - but be aware - the name and the .svc extension become part of your service's URL! Don't go too crazy on those names....

Answer (score 1):

I also had some problems with multiple endpoints within one service. I always got error 400. My error was not to use different addresses in the web.config. So it´s important to **use different address= configurations** for every endpoint (example is in the 1st post). One endpoint can omit it or leave it empty. All others need it.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to this discussion.

I was faced with the same problem and I ended up going with the use of a partial class.

Each endpoint can be implemented by a different interface as you have done, but your svc file refers to a single class name, you then split your class into partial classes and here's the clever bit, each partial class can implement a different interface.

You can then keep your implementations and interfaces separate but still get around the need for the svc file to refer to one class.